# Duda camino/tecnica para resolver condicionales

Tags: javascript

[image: condicionales]

Buenos tardes, el anterior mensaje sobre el input. se que se resuelve mediante una validacion con una expresion regular.
Pero que pasaria en dado caso de quererlo resolver mediante condicionales if,esto con el fin de practicar. por ejemplo

** el texto, puede tener o no tener guion bajo ( es opcional)
**  debe estar dentro de un rango  mayor o igual a 4 digitos y menor o igual a 16 digitos
**  puede tener numeros y letras

```
texto= "jhon123" // valido  
texto= "jhon_123" // valido 
texto= "j" // NO valido, tiene un solo digito
texto= "jhon_123#" // NO valido por el simbolo #
texto= "jhon12367890asdfg"  // NO valido por ser mayor  a  16 digitos
```

lo que hago es separar cada ambito a evaluar

```
evaluaSiesAlfaNumerico()     
texto.length >= 4 && texto.length  <= 16  
texto.includes("_") == true
```

y poner cada caso valido con **and** despues unirlos  mediante **or**

```
(evaluaSiesAlfaNumerico() == true && texto.length >= 4 && texto.length  <= 16  && texto.includes("_") == true )
||
(evaluaSiesAlfaNumerico() == true && texto.length >= 4 && texto.length  <= 16  && texto.includes("_") == false )
```

- este proceso, me costo muchisimo, en pensarlo  ustedes que tecnica usan, alguna recomendacion o pagina web
  para practicar este tipo de condicionales tardo demasiado en resolverlas.

Comment: Precisamente, para ahorrarte todo esas validaciones y ese proceso largo y tedioso, están las expresiones regulares.

Comment: [Constraint validation API - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation)